# Help with $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have been starting at the following integral for the past 2 hours and can not see where I have gone wrong. Can anyone please assist in isolating where I've made a mistake.

My sanity thanks you in advance,

\begin{equation*}
I = \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x}\:dx
\end{equation*}
Let $x = \tan(s)$:
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{dx}{ds} = \sec^2(s) \rightarrow dx = \sec^2(s)\:ds
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
    I &= \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x}\:dx =  \int \frac{\sqrt{\tan^2(s) + 1}}{\tan(s)}\cdot  \sec^2(s)\:ds = \int \frac{\sec(s)}{\tan(s)}\sec^2(s)\:ds = \int \frac{\sec^3(s)}{\tan(s)}\:ds \\
    &= \int \frac{\frac{1}{\cos^3(s)}}{\frac{\sin(s)}{\cos(s)}}\:ds = \int \frac{1}{\cos^3(s)} \cdot \frac{\cos(s)}{\sin(s)}\:ds = \int \frac{1}{\cos^2(s)\sin(s)}\:ds = \int \frac{1}{\left(1 - \sin^2(s)\right)\sin(s)}\:ds \\
    &= \int \frac{1}{\left(1 + \sin(s)\right)\left(1 - \sin(s)\right)\sin(s)}\:ds
\end{align*}
Applying a Partial Fraction Decomposition we see:
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{1}{\left(1 + \sin(s)\right)\left(1 - \sin(s)\right)\sin(s)} = \frac{1}{\sin(s)} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + \sin(s)} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1 - \sin(s)}
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
    I  &= \int \frac{1}{\left(1 + \sin(s)\right)\left(1 + \sin(s)\right)\sin(s)}\:ds =  \int \left[\frac{1}{\sin(s)} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + \sin(s)} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1 - \sin(s)} \right]\:ds \\
    &= \int \frac{1}{\sin(s)}\:ds - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1 + \sin(s)}\:ds  - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1 - \sin(s)}\:ds
\end{align*}
We now employ the Weierstrass Substitution $t = \tan\left(\frac{s}{2} \right)$:
\begin{equation*}
    ds = \frac{2}{1 + t^2}\:dt, \quad \sin(s) = \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}
\end{equation*}
Thus, 
\begin{align*}
   I&= \int \frac{1}{\sin(s)}\:ds - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1 + \sin(s)}\:ds  - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1 - \sin(s)}\:ds \\
    &= \int \frac{1}{\frac{2t}{1 + t^2}} \cdot \frac{2}{1 + t^2}\:dt - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}}\cdot \frac{2}{1 + t^2}\:dt  - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1 - \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}}\cdot \frac{2}{1 + t^2}\:dt \\
    &= \int \frac{1}{t}\:dt - \int \frac{1}{1 + t^2 + 2t}\:dt - \int \frac{1}{1 + t^2 - 2t}\:dt \\
    &= \int \frac{1}{t}\:dt - \int \frac{1}{\left(t + 1\right)^2}\:dt - \int \frac{1}{\left(t - 1\right)^2}\:dt = \ln\left|t\right| - -\frac{1}{t + 1} - - \frac{1}{t - 1} + C \\
    &= \ln\left|t\right| +\frac{1}{t + 1} + \frac{1}{t - 1} + C = \ln\left|t\right| +\frac{2t}{t^2 - 1} + C
\end{align*}
Where $C$ is the constant of integration. Here:
\begin{equation*}
    t = \tan\left(\frac{s}{2} \right) = \tan\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{2} \right) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}
\end{equation*}
Thus, 
\begin{align*}
   I&=  \ln\left|t\right| +\frac{2t}{t^2 - 1} + C = \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}\right| +\frac{2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}\right)}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x} \right)^2 - 1} + C \\
   &= \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}\right| + 2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}  \cdot \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x^2 + 1 - 2\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + 1}{x^2} \right) - 1} + C \\
   &= \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}\right| + 2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}  \cdot \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2 + 1 - 2\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + 1\right) - x^2} + C \\
  &= \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}\right| + 2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}  \cdot \frac{x^2}{2\left(1 - \sqrt{x^2 + 1} \right)} + C =  \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1}{x}\right| - x + C \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE. I have no criticisms of your post; the amount of your own work you gave us is awesome. In future posts, such effort is appreciated. Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks! and yes, I will :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is where you took $1-\sin^2 s=(1+\sin s)(1+\sin s).$ I believe this is just a slip and you know the right factorization.

The second one is that the decomposition into partial fractions is incorrect. We have that $$\frac1z-\frac12\left(\frac{1}{1+z}+\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\ne\frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}.$$

---

And to evaluate the $$\int\frac{\sec s}{\tan s}\sec^2s\mathrm ds,$$ you don't need to go to all this trouble. A little rewriting of the integrand helps, as follows: $$\frac{\sec s}{\tan s}\sec^2s=\frac{\sec s}{\tan s}(1+\tan^2s)=\frac{\sec s}{\tan s}+\sec s\tan s=\csc s+\sec s\tan s.$$

Comment: Yes, that's a typo on that line, hut the correct factorisation followed it.

Comment: @Allowonder - have now corrected.

Comment: @Allowander - Yes, it may be able to be resolved in a simpler manner. I'm still interested in isolating where I've made a mistake here.

Comment: @DavidGalea I didn't mean that that was a *typographical error.* I meant that it was a slip, a mistake that systematically affected everything else. In other words, this was your mistake. So changing only the first appearance doesn't change everything else after it. You need to change everything else affected by this wrong factorisation to get the right thing. :)

Comment: No I appreciate that. If you read my process you'll see that I've used the correct factorisation following that. In this case, it is just a typographical error.

Comment: @DavidGalea Oh, yes yes. I can see that now, although this typo is used almost systematically -- it still appears above (but I can understand why). Anyhow I believe I've now caught the main culprit for you. See my edited answer above. :)

Comment: (+1) @Allawonder Sorry, but can you please elaborate on why $1-\sin^2 s=(1+\sin s)(1+\sin s)$ is incorrect?

Comment: @Allawonder - Thanks for noticing that. This leaves me stunned. I used wolframalpha (out of laziness) to get the partial fraction decomposition!

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28x*%281+%2B+x%29*%281+-+x%29%29

Comment: @NoLand'sMan - It was written differently when he commented that. I have edited and corrected the typographical error.

Comment: Oh alright, thanks.

Comment: @NoLand'sMan If you expand RHS, you do not get LHS. Try it! :)

Comment: Ah, now I see what I did wrong. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Allawonder Oh! I didn't notice that there are 2 positive signs, my bad :)

Comment: An easier way is to let $\sqrt{x^2+1}=u$ to have 

$$I=\int\frac{u^2\ du}{u^2-1}=u-\tanh^{-1}u=\sqrt{x^2+1}-\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{x^2+1}+C$$

Answer (score 2):

In some cases trigonometric substitution should be avoided

$$\displaystyle I=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}xdx=\int x\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2}dx$$

Let $\sqrt{1+x^2}=u\implies1+x^2=u^2,x\ dx=u \ du$

$$I=\int\dfrac u{u^2-1}udu=1+\dfrac1{u^2-1}=1+\dfrac{1+u+1-u}{(1+u)(1-u)}=?$$

Comment: Absolutely. That's not what was asked here though.